# Is there a way to set the alignment of the QTextEdit.placeholderText() in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I know you can set the alignment of the *text* using `setAlignment()`, but that has no effect on the *placeholder text*. Maybe you would need to edit the `styleSheet` of the underlying `document`in order to do it? Or is the document only relevant for the actual text but not the placeholder?

Here's an MWE to play around with:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QGridLayout, QTextEdit


class Test(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        self.edit.setPlaceholderText(
            # '<html><body><p align="center">'
            'this is a placeholder'
            # '</p></body></html>'
        )
        self.edit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.lay = QGridLayout(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Test()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder cannot be directly customized, as it is directly painted by the QTextEdit using the default top alignment, so the only solution is to subclass, overwrite the paintEvent and paint the placeholder using your own alignment.

You might also add much more control by using a QTextDocument, which will allow you to use html and custom colors/alignment/etc.

[image: html placeholder text]

```
class HtmlPlaceholderTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    _placeholderText = ''
    def setPlaceholderText(self, text):
        if Qt.mightBeRichText(text):
            self._placeholderText = QTextDocument()
            try:
                color = self.palette().placeholderText().color()
            except:
                # for Qt < 5.12
                color = self.palette().windowText().color()
                color.setAlpha(128)
            # IMPORTANT: the default stylesheet _MUST_ be set *before*
            # adding any text, otherwise it won't be used.
            self._placeholderText.setDefaultStyleSheet(
                '''body {{color: rgba({}, {}, {}, {});}}
                '''.format(*color.getRgb()))
            self._placeholderText.setHtml(text)
        else:
            self._placeholderText = text
        self.update()

    def placeholderText(self):
        return self._placeholderText

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self.document().isEmpty() and self.placeholderText():
            qp = QPainter(self.viewport())
            margin = self.document().documentMargin()
            r = QRectF(self.viewport().rect()).adjusted(margin, margin, -margin, -margin)
            text = self.placeholderText()
            if isinstance(text, str):
                try:
                    color = self.palette().placeholderText().color()
                except:
                    # for Qt < 5.12
                    color = self.palette().windowText().color()
                    color.setAlpha(128)
                qp.setPen(color)
                qp.drawText(r, self.alignment() | Qt.TextWordWrap, text)
            else:
                text.setPageSize(self.document().pageSize())
                text.drawContents(qp, r)


class Test(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.edit = HtmlPlaceholderTextEdit()
        self.edit.setPlaceholderText(
            '<html><body><p align="center">'
            'this is a <font color="blue">placeholder</font>'
            '</p></body></html>'
        )
        # ...
```

Comment: What does `setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)` do at its core that it cannot simply be also applied to the placeholder text? I mean I like the freedom and versatility that comes with the html coding, but why not have that switch also work for the placeholder text?

Comment: @mapf [`alignment()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#alignment) is not a global property of QTextEdit; as [`setAlignment()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setAlignment) reports: «Sets the alignment of the **current paragraph**». QTextEdit is not a simple line edit: it supports rich text, which means that it can have multiple paragraphs, each on them with different styles, alignments, etc. So, since you might use setAlignment() at different points in the whole document, it wouldn't make much sense to use that for the placeholder too, as they are not related (nor they should be).

Comment: Aaah, I see, thank you! Still it would be cool to have all this functionality that you have with the regular text also with the placeholder text. Oh well.

Comment: @mapf I suppose that the placeholder text functionality is not used that much on QTextEdit to require additional implementation (it is usually enough to use the default visual alignment of the system, which is the default behavior), I don't even see any feature request about it on Qt's bug report system.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess this is a special case then. Thanks for having a look!